# Angular MVC project - getting 404 with templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to access an edit partial from another folder (AddEditPersonModal.cshtml) in my mvc project, then load the contents in a ui bootstrap modal thru angular.  When the index.cshtml page loads I get a 404 error on that very partial.  Here's my code:

Angular:

```
 $scope.editPerson = function (person) {
    $scope.modalModel = person;
    //getModal(person);
    $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/Modal/AddEditPersonModal.cshtml',
        controller: 'modalController',
        scope: $scope
    })
    resolve: {
            person: {
                return $scope.person;
            }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-model="editPersonModel" ng-click="editPerson(person)"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span></a>
```

**Error:**

```
    angular.js:12011 GET http://localhost:58227/Modal/AddEditPersonModal.cshtml 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12011n @ angular.js:11776(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11571(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16383$eval @ angular.js:17682$digest @ angular.js:17495scopePrototype.$digest @ hint.js:1364$apply @ angular.js:17790scopePrototype.$apply @ hint.js:1427(anonymous function) @ angular.js:25890dispatch @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3
angular.js:13920 Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$compile/tpload?p0=%2FModal%2FAddEditPersonModal.cshtml&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:19433
    at angular.js:16383
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17682)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:17495)
    at m.scopePrototype.$digest (hint.js:1364)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:17790)
    at m.scopePrototype.$apply (hint.js:1427)
    at l (angular.js:11831)
    at J (angular.js:12033)
```

ModalController:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEditPersonModal(DTOPerson model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: what is the path of your `AddEditPersonModal.cshtml` file?

Comment: ~Views/Modal/AddEditPersonModal.cshtml when i run the debugger in vs2015 thats the path it takes me to for it...

Comment: The `template-url` should be relative to the application root path. for example, if your views in the root, then use. 'Views/Modal/AddEditPersonModal.cshtml',

Comment: You need a controller method named `AddEditPersonModal()` that returns the `.cshtml` file - `public ActionResult AddEditPersonModal() { return View(); }`

Comment: Same error: Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Views/Modal/AddEditPersonModal.cshtml

Comment: I forgot to add my controller method, added that in OP

Comment: @tshoemake, You cannot navigate to a `.cshtml` file in MVC - you navigate to controller methods that return views. - `templateUrl: '/Modal/AddEditPersonModal',`

Comment: @StephenMuecke angular.js:12011 GET http://localhost:58227/Modal/AddEditPersonModal 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Remove the `[HttpPost]` :)

Comment: You're the man thats it, thanks again @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC, you navigate to controller methods that return views, not to the view file itself. Change the script to

```
$uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: '/Modal/AddEditPersonModal', // amend
    controller: 'modalController',
    scope: $scope
})
```

and remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute from your `AddEditPersonModal()` method (it's making a GET request, not a POST)